# CSS psuedo-element content: attr(type)?

Tags: css

I just want a rule that acts like so:

```
div:before {
    content: "div";
}
span:before {
    content: "span";
}
a:before {
    content: "a";
}
```

but I want it to be generic for all element types, not just a div.

I want this...

```
*:before {
    content: attr(tagname); 
}
```

But `tagname` is not an attribute. Is there any way to get the element's type as a string in CSS?

Comment: looks like this can't be done with just CSS, you have to use script

Comment: What are you saying? Do you want to have `type` as your content for pseudo elements regardless of the tag, or are you trying to exempt `<div>` elements? I left an answer, but if you clarify, we can better help you.

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it would not be relevant given your clarification.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify: I'm looking for the type of the element (the tag name), not the actual `type` attribute.

Comment: You can set for example just one CSS rule *:before{content: attr(rel);} and then write rel="div", rel="span" and so in every html element. Or you can specify one CSS rule for every html element (like in your question). Otherwise, it's not possible to do with CSS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. [Generated content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html) can be specified in a few ways only. What you are trying to do requires client-side scripting, perhaps so that CSS rules are dynamically added to elements, and in the script code, you can use the tag name from the element node.